# My MySQL query isn't passed even when it looks like I have the right output in a Leetcode problem

Tags: sql, mysql

This is the leetcode problem:

> Table: `Signups`
>
> | user_id | conf_rate |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 0 |
> | 7 | 1 |
> | 2 | 0.5 |
> | 6 | 0 |
>
> `user_id` is the column of unique values for this table.
> Each row contains information about the signup time for the user with ID `user_id`.
>
> Table: `Confirmations`
>
> | Column Name | Type |
> | --- | --- |
> | user_id | int |
> | time_stamp | datetime |
> | action | ENUM |
>
> `(user_id, time_stamp)` is the primary key (combination of columns with unique values) for this table.
> `user_id` is a foreign key (reference column) to the `Signups` table.
> `action` is an ENUM (category) of the type `('confirmed', 'timeout')`.
> Each row of this table indicates that the user with ID `user_id` requested a confirmation message at time_stamp and that confirmation message was either confirmed (`'confirmed'`) or expired without confirming (`'timeout'`).
>
> The confirmation rate of a user is the number of `'confirmed'` messages divided by the total number of requested confirmation messages. The confirmation rate of a user that did not request any confirmation messages is 0. Round the confirmation rate to two decimal places.
>
> Write a solution to find the confirmation rate of each user.
>
> Return the result table in any order.
>
> The result format is in the following example.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input:
> `Signups` table:
>
> | user_id | time_stamp |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 2020-03-21 10:16:13 |
> | 7 | 2020-01-04 13:57:59 |
> | 2 | 2020-07-29 23:09:44 |
> | 6 | 2020-12-09 10:39:37 |
>
> `Confirmations` table:
>
> | Column Name | Type |
> | --- | --- |
> | user_id | int |
> | time_stamp | datetime |
> | action | ENUM |
>
> Output:
>
> | user_id | confirmation_rate |
> | --- | --- |
> | 6 | 0.00 |
> | 3 | 0.00 |
> | 7 | 1.00 |
> | 2 | 0.50 |
>
> Explanation:
>
> - User 6 did not request any confirmation messages. The confirmation rate is 0.
> - User 3 made 2 requests and both timed out. The confirmation rate is 0.
> - User 7 made 3 requests and all were confirmed. The confirmation rate is 1.
> - User 2 made 2 requests where one was confirmed and the other timed out. The confirmation rate is 1 / 2 = 0.5.

This is my solution:

```sql
SELECT s.user_id, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(s.user_id), 2) as rate
FROM signups s
  LEFT JOIN confirmations c ON s.user_id = c.user_id
GROUP BY 1
```

My output:

| user_id | conf_rate |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.5 |
| 6 | 0 |

I am apparently getting the identical output to the expected result set but the query is not getting passed.

Comment: Did I make it right?

Comment: The query looks good. I don't see any flaw that would explain why your query doesn't pass. `count(s.user_id)` is simply `count(*)` of course, which I prefer, because we count rows here. We count expressions instead, when we explicitly want to exclude nulls. `SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(action = 'confirmed')` in MySQL, because they treat true as 1 and false as 0. And I don't like positional `GROUP BY` very much. But that is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

> The confirmation rate of a user is the number of 'confirmed' messages divided by the total number of requested confirmation messages. The confirmation rate of a user that did not request any confirmation messages is 0. Round the confirmation rate to two decimal places.

This means that if the user has some records in the `confirmations` table, then your `SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(s.user_id)` is correct. But reread carefully the quoted text. It says that if there are no records in the `confirmation` table for the user, then you need to default it to 0. Your

```
SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(s.user_id)
```

seems to do that, because when your have an unmatched record, then the ungrouped left join will yield a single record, where the `confirmations` values are all `null`, including the `action`, which, on its turn will differ from `'confirmed'` and result in `0`, whereas `count(s.user_id)` will be 1 in this case. But you may decide to make your formula more explicit and therefore more readable:

```
CASE
    WHEN MAX(action) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE
         SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(s.user_id)
END
```

Finally, let's compare your results with the results expected from you. You may say that 1 is the exact same as 1.00, but this is an actually different format. Hence, you will also need to cast your result so that it will have exactly two decimal precision for all results:

```
CAST(
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(action) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE
             SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(s.user_id)
    END
    AS DECIMAL(6, 2)
)
```

Comment: This query is not working either. Same problem. The result set is same, but it's not accepted

Comment: This part `SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(action = 'confirmed')` in `MySQL`

Comment: @Azimovsky please edit your question and add 1. The exact query you have tried to execute, 2. The exact result that you had, 3. The sample results, 4. Any guidance about what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @JonasMetzler yes, because logical evaluations evaluate to 1 (true) or 0 (false). But using these shortcuts makes the code less readable in my opinion, because whoever has to work on such a code will have to ponder about the syntax rather than the algorithm.

Comment: @LajosArpad I disagree with your opinion because I think it is "less readable" to write a useless `ELSE` clause. Even if you dislike the shortened sum syntax, I would avoid the `ELSE` clause and write `COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'confirmed' THEN 1 END)` instead.

Comment: @JonasMetzler it makes the code explicit. Think about the difficulty of changing the default, especially for those, who did not work on this feature earlier.